# Lumia Imaging SDK throws System.TypeLoadException: Lumia.Imaging.StorageFileImageSource is not registered

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, lumia-imaging-sdk

I've used Lumia Imaging SDK (ver 2) for compressing images in my Windows Phone 8.1 RT application. The code for compression randomly throws the following exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type.
>   Requested Windows Runtime type 'Lumia.Imaging.StorageFileImageSource' is not registered.,
>
> Message: Failure has occurred while loading a type.,
>   Stacktrace: at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)
>     at Lumia.Imaging.StorageFileImageSource..ctor(IStorageFile storageFile)

How can I fix this?

**Update:** I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5. Details [image: here].

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you on? We have seen a similar problem a while ago, but it turned out to be a tools problem not related to the SDK itself.

Comment: Searching on the web it looks like it was a Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 issue.

Comment: @DavidBožjak I'm using Visual Studio 2013, Update 5, but still face the issue. Please refer to [this](http://i.imgur.com/VQWx6Lw.png) screenshot for detailed version information.